# How to deal with password security when sending credentials to a REST authentication endpoint?

Tags: android, rest, security, passwords

My question arises from the assumption that it's best practice not to handle passwords as `String` in a JVM environment. Android actually handles text inside `EditText`s as array of `char` and provides a `getChars` method to get such array.

Given that I can handle a password this way, what happens when I have to serialize it to put it in a request body? Should I receive it on my server endpoint as `char[]`? Even with this option, client-side it will be eventually serialized to something like `['p','w','d']` which is again, a `String`.

To try to figure this out, I observed outbound traffic from a device to Amazon's authentication endpoints and there's actually my password in plain sight in a request body; so my question may even turn into: how big of a concern is this whole passwords vs Strings matter (at least in Android)?

Edit: an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) of why I have this concern.

Comment: You don't have to serialize value from edit text. A simple editext.getText().toString() will give you the string

Comment: And if you are concerned with security, you can encrypt password using algorithm like md5 and then decrypt it on your server

Comment: As an extra layer of security, you can enforce certificate pinning on your server and client to avoid MITM.

Comment: @VivekMishra I don't want to represent the password value as a String, because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords). This is the premise of my question

Comment: @Tejas the vulnerability here is about accessing the app's process memory, not related to SSL.

Comment: @VivekMishra also I think hashing the password only hides the original word(s), it doesn't prevent an attacker to dump the String hash and use it to authenticate. And md5 cannot be decrypted, it's a one-way hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using `hash` function while sending it on your API.

Comment: I think hashing the password only hides the original word(s), it doesn't prevent an attacker to dump the String hash and use it to authenticate.